# HAVING vs WHERE performance with computed columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am toying between two different ways to query my MySQL database using either WHERE or HAVING. The queries look something like this (they are formed dynamically according to user input):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE books.ratings_sum/books.ratings_count > 2 
AND books.ratings_sum/books.ratings_count < 4 
ORDER BY books.ratings_sum/books.ratings_count DESC;
```

```sql
SELECT *, books.ratings_sum/books.ratings_count as avg_rating 
FROM books 
HAVING avg_rating > 2
AND avg_rating < 4
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC;
```

I'm wondering which would be more performant. I understand that HAVING applies very little optimisation since it filters the results after the query has already returned rows, so that WHERE would have an advantage. But the WHERE clause seems to calculate the average rating 3 times for each row, possibly outweighing any benefits. Unless it is smart enough to only calculate it once per row? Could anyone shed some light on this please?

Thankyou.

Comment: Is the second query even legal? What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Just because an expression appears three times in a query doesn't mean it is evaluated three times. The optimizer should be smart enough to catch the repetition and evaluate it only once reusing the result for the other two occurences.

Comment: In any case, those two queries produce different results. You shouldn't compare apples to oranges.

Comment: @stickybit I see, that's what I was hoping would happen, just wanted to make sure. Thanks for that.

Comment: @TheImpaler yes that's my bad, I typed the question after a long day. Will edit so they are equivalent now. Yes the second query is legal, I just double-checked. I'm using version 5.7.25 with mamp. Cheers

Comment: `HAVING` is not meant to be used that way.  `HAVING` is to filter aggregation, which you don't have in this case.  So start with a good habit, and don't use `HAVING` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is any difference, the HAVING version is probably going to be slower. It's going to ignore any indexes you have, filtering results after collecting all the data contained in the table.

WHERE with calculations will not be able to use indexes either, so it still has to inspect the entire table like the HAVING version does, but it will only collect the rows that fit the criteria.

*Simple mathematical operations like those used are extremely inexpensive compared to reading data.*

Roughly/potentially speaking...
The HAVING version will have to read every field of every row. The WHERE version will have to read the `ratings_sum` and `ratings_count` fields of every row, but only the rest of the fields when the condition on those fields are met.

....this is assuming the query optimizer doesn't re-interpret them to the same plan internally (and assuming you use the same conditions on both, unlike the versions presented in the question).